# Sanctified or being sanctified Hebrew 10:14

Tags: greek, grammar, hebrews

Focusing purely on the Greek grammar is it saying those who are being sanctified or those who are sanctified?

> μια γαρ προσφορα τετελειωκεν εις το διηνεκες τους **αγιαζομενους**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

αγιαζομενους is the present passive participle of ἁγιάζω - so it means those being sanctified (lit. "the being sanctified").

Some translations choose to translate the phrase along the lines of "those that are sanctified" (e.g. KJV, RSV).  The ESV translation is more accurate:

> *For by a single offering he has perfected for all time those who are being sanctified.*

Comment: Would you be so kind to elaborate if you know why those translations say those that are sanctified (seemingly implying an already complete sanctification). Thank you.

Comment: No, I really don't know why to be honest.  Perhaps some translators wanted to impute some theological bias, but that would only be speculation on my part.  Sorry.  It sounds like an interesting discussion, but I don't have anything to go on.